# command not found: nodejs-backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm trying to create my own package that will initialize the boiler plate project by running node package execute `npx`. I once created one using `node.js` and `inquirer` and it worked when I run:

```
npx ts-config-files.json
```

This is the [package](https://github.com/CrispenGari/tsconfig.json) that I've created and published on `npm` that generates `tsconfigs`.

The one that I've just created when i run the command:

```
npx nodejs-backend
```

I get this:

```
npx: installed 135 in 47.951s
command not found: nodejs-backend
```

Instead of getting some `inquirer` messages. The code of what i'm working on can be found [here](https://github.com/CrispenGari/nodejs-backend).

**I've been thinking it's because I'm using `typescript` but when i changed to `javascript` it's still the same thing.**

##### Sample code of the main file `server.ts`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import path from "path";
import inquirer from "inquirer";
import { writeFile, readFile } from "fs/promises";
import fs from "fs";
import helperFunction from "./constants";
import { exec } from "child_process";
import { objJS, objTS } from "./utils";
import chalk from "chalk";

helperFunction.prompt();
const cwd = process.cwd();
const base_name = path.basename(cwd); // node

const main = async () => {
  const baseDir: string = "src";
  let fileName: string = "";
  let packageObject: typeof objTS | typeof objJS;
  const { language } = await inquirer.prompt([
    {
      choices: ["JavaScript", "TypeScript"],
      type: "checkbox",
      default: "TypeScript",
      name: "language",
      message: "which language do you want to use for your backend app?",
    },
  ]);
....
```

Comment: The package not exist on npm so npx couldn’t find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add:

```
"bin": {
  "nodejs-backend": "server.ts"
},
```

Which should be in `package.json`.

Also after that make sure to `npm link` in your repo before trying to use `npx` otherwise it will try install it from the https://registry.npmjs.org registry instead of local.

That being said I'm fairly certain it won't execute as typescript even if you've done that (which isn't your issue right now but it will be).  For that you can install `ts-node` and use `#! /usr/bin/env ts-node`.